# Show Bootstrap tool-tip one-time on page load and hide after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to add a tooltip-shaped alert to a specific element in my page, which appears only once. So if the user, for example clicks 'X' on the alert, it will now show again. Below is the element that I'm trying to add the alert to.

```
<div class="name-wrapper">
    <span class="usermain-name">     
        User name
    </span>
</div>
```

So if the user enters the page that has this element, I want to have a tooltip appear right above the `User name`, that says "click here to edit your name". And as mentioned above, it has to appear only once. I'm a newbie in front-end and have no idea on how to create this. I'm using Bootstrap, if it provides any additional information. 
 I very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: which version of Bootstrap do you use? Do you use jQuery?

Comment: you can use on page load function for this.

Comment: You can fire a click event listener with an option of once, it will get executed just once.

Comment: @refatalsakka I"m using Bootstrap 4 :)

Comment: @NitishPhanse Is there other event listener, aside from click? Because I want the alert to show up immediately after the page is loaded

Comment: See the working solution below exactly as you wanted and simplified as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in bootstrap 4 by using `jQuery` and bootstrap `tooltip` functions.

Using `data-toggle="tooltip`" `data-placement="top"` in your `username` element

The tool tip will appear on page loads and will disappear after 3 seconds.

Run Snippet below.

```js
//Show tooltip on page load
$('span').tooltip('show');

//Hide tooltip after three seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  $('span').tooltip('dispose')
}, 3000)
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="name-wrapper">
  <span class="usermain-name" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="I will appear only once">     
        User name
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But just one thing: Is there any way I can make it appear just once? The user has to check the alert just one time, and never after. Will I have to use cookie?

Comment: @RyanOh Yes in that case you have to use cookie. But ideally best practice and for better user experience  load the tool-tip every time user visit the page. It upto what best best for you and what the scope is. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

Html:

```
<a href="#"title="Download Excel" class="tool_tip">Download Excel</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.tool_tip')
.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
.attr('data-placement', 'right')
.tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  })
  .tooltip('show')


  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.tool_tip').tooltip('hide') // it will be disappeared after 5 seconds
  }, 5000);
```